# android WiFi scanner, list only networks with specific SSID

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi

I need to create WiFi scanner app on android device. I managed to do it, yet there is something I don't know how to deal with.

```
    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        Comparator<ScanResult> comparator = new Comparator<ScanResult>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ScanResult o1, ScanResult o2) {
                return (o1.level>o2.level ? -1 : (o1.level==o2.level ? 0 : 1));
            }
        };
        lista = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            scanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults().get(i);
            sb.append(new Integer(i + 1).toString() + ". " + (list.get(i)).SSID + "  " + (list.get(i)).BSSID + "  " + (list.get(i)).level + "\n");
        }
        txt.setText(sb);
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }
}
```

There are several WiFi networks in the building with the same SSID, lets say `ABCD`. I want to save in `list`, which is `List<ScanResult>` type, only networks with this specific SSID `ABCD` without the need to create another field such as `list` if possible. I woukd be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want a way to filter the scan and return only the specified ssid, there is no way that I know of on the back-end to do that. You can go through your existing list and pull out the ones you want and save to a new List.
You can also use your existing code and check to see if the ssid matches inside your loop and only build the string if it does.
Most of the time you will be showing a list of available networks in a list or recycler view so usually the secondary list is the way to go.